# Find all tags enclosed with [[tag]], loop through each one and lookup accordingly in php

Tags: php, regex, loops

I'm trying to find all occurances of all the tags, say, [[tag1]] [[tag2]] [[tag3]] etc, then loop through each and sorting them out accordingly.

I'm comfortable doing the loops etc but wondering if someone could help me with finding all tags that are enclosed in [[]], return the array so I can sort out whatever it returns in a loop?

Many thanks girls and guys!

Comment: When you say the "sort out", what do you mean?  Lookup tables? Some form of processing?  Are they nested (like BB code), or flat? etc.

Comment: For sorting out I mean look up each tag code and replace text accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an array with all tags:

```
$text = '[[tag1]] [[tag2]] [[tag3]]';
$pattern = '/\\[\\[(.*)\\]\\]/sU';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $hits);
$tags = $hits[1];
print_r($tags);
```

Comment: Why `i`?  There's no text in your pattern, so there's nothing to make case insensitive...

Comment: You're right. I removed the "i". Just copied it from some of my code where I needed the pattern to be case insensitive

Comment: I might ask the same question about the s modifier.  I think it would be unlikely for a tag name to have a newline in it.

Comment: Superb! Thanks guys and Merry Christmas (or happy holidays)!

Comment: @russ: Yea I'm sure you could leave the "s" out as well.